# OnTouch is returning "false" but touch event is not passing to underlying view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, service

One service is started from MainActivity

```
public void buttonClicked(View v){
    //method to call after button is clicked in MainActivity

    if(v.getTag() == null){
        globalService = new Intent(this,GlobalTouchService.class);
        startService(globalService);//start the service
        v.setTag("on");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        stopService(globalService);
        v.setTag(null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stop Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Inside OnCreate of the service, one transparent layout is created and Touch Listener is implemented.

```
public class GlobalService extends Service{
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // create linear layout
        touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    // set on touch listener
    //touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    // fetch window manager object
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    // set layout parameter of window manager
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;


    mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);
     touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Action :" + event.getAction() + "\t X :" + event.getRawX() + "\t Y :"+ event.getRawY());

            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

Since onTouch is returning false, control should move to the background MainActivity when we click above transparent layout.
But it is not . What may be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the control should move to the background MainActivity - that would be a ***major*** security risk, since you would be able to implement something like a touch event logger. Once you have a list of logged touch events, you can map them to the coordinates of separate keyboard keys and leak a user's password!

It makes absolutely no sense for the OS to behave in such a way.

Comment: Please check this document :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html
    True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
if you return false, someone else will handle the event

Comment: Keep in mind that your touchLayout is not part of the Activity's View hierarchy - what you linked only applies to other views at the same coordinates in the same view hierarchy as far as I know.

Comment: so, any other way I can send event to the background Activity to handle ?

Comment: Hm, what is your use case more precisely? Does it HAVE to be a Service and does the Activity have to implement the handling code? Maybe you need to redesign your code. Adding a View from a Service is hacky enough, maybe you shouldn't be doing that in the first place, let alone adding more hacks on top of it.

Comment: Yes...I need to handle touch events from outside the activity.About any other "Hack" you know ?

Answer (score 0):

As the Service is not part of your activity, all the events that you get into it won't reach the activity. If what you want is just let the events pass through you can do it by making your new layer not touchable:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

But you have to take into account that you **won't** get the events in the listener.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to get event informations from the service and pass it to background activity.Any other way to achieve that ?